# passing the values of a list as parameters in python

Tags: python, list

I have the following function in python:

```
from itertools import product as get_cartesian_product 
from arithmetic import get_iterable_sum


def get_number_of_solutions(*possible_variables, target):
    number_of_solutions = 0
    for comb in get_cartesian_product(possible_variables):
        if get_iterable_sum(comb) == target:
            number_of_solutions += 1
    return number_of_solutions
```

and the following list in main.py:

```
variables_possiblities = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```

I want to pass, not the array, but the values of the array, [1, 3...], [1, 3...], [0, 2...], as the parameters in the function and then get their cartesian product, how can I do that?

Comment: What issues are you currently having by passing your list as a parameter? Note: target param should ideally go first

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from itertools import product as get_cartesian_product 
from arithmetic import get_iterable_sum


def get_number_of_solutions(possible_variables, target):
    number_of_solutions = 0
    for comb in get_cartesian_product(*possible_variables):
        if get_iterable_sum(comb) == target:
            number_of_solutions += 1
    return number_of_solutions

variables_possiblities = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
get_number_of_solutions(variables_possiblities,target=2)
```

Comment: why  should I add [0]?

Comment: @talopl where??

Comment: *possible_variables[0], it doesn't work without it

Comment: @talopl If you use my code this will work fine.